# On which thread does an object of C++/CX class get destroyed, if it is a field inside a C# object?

Tags: c#, multithreading, garbage-collection, destructor, c++-cx

There is a C++/CX WinRT component class **CppCx**:

`public ref class CppCx sealed {
    ...
}`

There is also a C# class **CSharp** that holds a field of type **CppCx**:

`public class CSharp {
    ...
    private CppCx theField;
    ...
}`

I know that the memory for objects of type **CSharp** is collected on GC's thread, but on which thread does **theField**'s destructor get called?

This is important for thread-safety reasons - e.g. **theField** can hold native C++ objects that are being accessed on background threads.

Comment: The CLR takes care of it, the finalizer thread makes the IUnknown::Release() call.  Nothing you can easily see.

Comment: Hi Hans! I think I didn't state my question clear enough - edited it now. Also, added an example when it can be a source of problems with thread-safety.

Comment: Smells like inappropriate class design, if an internal member of a WinRT component is used outside the class, on another thread. *Encapsulation* is meant to prevent this from becoming an issue.

Comment: "On another thread" does not have to mean "outside the class". WinRT component itself can be encapsulating that other thread. A more general problem here is that reference counting is usually contrasted with garbage collection as kind of a deterministic construction <-> destruction bond; and it appears to be broken here. Well, maybe it's just my intuition:) Anyway, will test it this week, and post the results.

Comment: Why haven't you made `CSharp` implement `IDisposable`, and explicitly dealt with the issue?

Comment: @arootbeer - I actually ended up with IDisposable. And this question helped a lot in understanding the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On a thread that will "destroy" the last reference to that WinRT component.

If it is a GC thread, then GC thread will call the destructor.

Comment: This is a straightforward answer to quite an interesting question - when down-voting it - speak up! Don't be so shy.